# jQuery Cycle 2 - Per slide Pager not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am implementing a [Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php) slider [here](http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/about/day-in-the-life-of-a-caregiver/).

Everything is working correctly except the Per-Slide Template pager which should be showing the custom pager text that is included with each image.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=fade
    data-cycle-timeout=5000
    pause-on-hover=true
    data-cycle-pager="#per-slide-template"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    >

    <div class="slide">
    <h3 class="shift">Morning Shift </h3>
    <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="text-box">
                    <h3>8:00 a.m.</h3>
                        <p>Arrive at the client’s home, greet him or her with a friendly smile, and learn from the client how you can be of assistance that day. Remind the client to take medications and assist with grooming and dressing if needed. </p>
            </div>
                <img src="http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/images/uploads/am-8.png" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>8am</a>">
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slide -->

    <div class="slide">
    <h3 class="shift">Morning Shift </h3>
    <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="text-box">
                    <h3>10:00 a.m.</h3>
                        <p>Play a game of cards together, scrapbook, look at photos, reminisce or listen to music to provide some vital mental stimulation and engagement, particularly for a client with dementia or Alzheimer’s. </p>
            </div>
                <img src="http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/images/uploads/am-10.png" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>10am</a>">
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slide -->

    <div class="slide">
    <h3 class="shift">Morning Shift </h3>
    <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="text-box">
                    <h3>11:00 a.m.</h3>
                        <p>If the weather is nice, take a walk around the block or to the park with the client to get some exercise. While the client is resting after the walk, do some other light housekeeping. Then prepare and serve lunch, and make sure the client has everything he or she needs.</p>
            </div>
                <img src="http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/images/uploads/am-11.png" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>11am</a>">
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slide -->

    <div class="slide">
    <h3 class="shift">Evening Shift</h3>
    <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="text-box">
                    <h3>2:00 p.m.</h3>
                        <p>Run errands if the client needs medications from the pharmacy or a grocery run. Take the client on a trip to the barber, hairdresser or the library. </p>
            </div>
                <img src="http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/images/uploads/pm-2.png" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>2pm</a>">
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slide -->

    <div class="slide">
    <h3 class="shift">Evening Shift </h3>
    <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="text-box">
                    <h3>5:30 p.m.</h3>
                        <p>Prepare a special meal that the client can assist with in whatever way he or she is able.</p>
            </div>
                <img src="http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/images/uploads/pm-5.png" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>5:30pm</a>">
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slide -->

    <div class="slide">
    <h3 class="shift">Evening Shift/Overnight </h3>
    <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="text-box">
                    <h3>9:00 p.m.</h3>
                        <p>Help the client prepare for bed. This may involve assisting the client with bathing and dressing. Some clients require overnight assistance from a caregiver or LNA. Caregivers stay at the client’s home to assist as needed throughout the night with using the bathroom, trouble sleeping or other necessities.</p>
            </div>
                <img src="http://livefreehomehealthcare.com/images/uploads/pm-9.png" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>9pm</a>">
        </div>
    </div><!-- end slide -->

</div>
<!-- empty element for pager links -->
<div id=per-slide-template class="center internal"></div>
```

Instead of the times that are there, the output is like this, which appears to be the default pager output.

```
div id="per-slide-template" class="center internal">
<span class="">•</span>
<span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span>
<span class="">•</span>
<span class="">•</span>
<span class="">•</span>
<span class="">•</span>
</div>
```

Any guidance on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution. Because I am using a div as the slide element, the pager code has to go in the div, not in the image:

```
data-cycle-pager-template="<a href=#>5:30pm</a>"
```

As soon as I placed that, it solved the problem.